# Formatting string to print to serial in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I am just wondering how exactly Serial.println works in the Arduino IDE. I am currently trying to print some info to the console so that I can read it in MATLAB. I originally tried the following code,

```
Serial.println("Time_Param\t%i\tid\t%i", START_DELAY_TIME, TRANSIENT_TIME, DEPOSITION_TIME);
```

however, this did not compile, with the following message,

*Compilation error: no matching function for call to 'HardwareSerial::println(const char [20], long int&, long int&, long int&)*.

When I try seperating everything like so,

```
    Serial.print("Time_PARAM");
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(START_DELAY_TIME);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(TRANSIENT_TIME);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(DEPOSITION_TIME);
    Serial.print("\n");
```

it works as I was hoping. Would somebody be able to explain what exactly the difference is between these? On the Arduino website it says that it takes any data type. Thank you for the help.

Comment: From a quick look at [the documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/println/), `println` doesn't look like a `printf`-analogue. I think the gang of calls is the best you can do unless you `sprintf` to a buffer and `println` the buffer.

Comment: [`println`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/println/) is not a var args function. It only takes 1 or 2 parameters. If you want your own `printf` type function to print to serial you can make a var args function that uses `vprintf`.

Comment: Ah, alright, that makes sense! I didn't realize that the input I gave provided multiple inputs, I had just assumed it worked the same as sprintf inside the println. Thanks for the explanation, you helped a very tired grad student out haha

Comment: You can use `std::ostringstream` for formatting then bulk write the `std::string` to the Serial Port.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Serial class does not have a `printf` style function. Here's a wrapper function you can use:

```
int ser_printf(const char *format, ...)
{
    static char buffer[1024]; // Adjust to your needs
    va_list aptr;
    va_start(aptr, format);
    int results = vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), format, aptr);
    va_end(aptr);
    Serial.print(buffer);
    return results;
}
```

Example:

```
ser_printf("Time_Param\t%i\t%i\t%i\n", START_DELAY_TIME, TRANSIENT_TIME, DEPOSITION_TIME);
```